# Why RSA2048 sign of Intel accelerate card is fast?

Tags: rsa, circuit

[Intel accelerate card](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/quickassist-adapter-8950-brief.pdf)

This card executes rsa2048 sign 35K ops(operation/second). My fast version is only 100 ops.

I can't find any HSM paper that has same performance level.

I am interested in this problem. I know modexp, montgomery, crt, PE-array and some other circuit skills, but I can't reach such a high performance.

Could someone give me a hand please? Thanks very much.

Comment: Note that unlike what some people claim, HSMs _are not built to be fast, they are built to be secure_. Also on a modern CPU you can [expect about 3-5M cycles for a single RSA signature](https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-sign.html) on a CPU with speculation which easily yields ~500 signatures per second and core and so you'd only need about 64 such cores packed on a PCIe card to reach this level of performance. Without fancy advanced ILP optimzations you can still get away with ~4 times the cores (?) so not unlike what Xeon Phis did. Or of course HW support will probably make all this much faster.

Comment: @SEJPM, thanks. I will use new key words when I serch online. You mean 64*500=32000, but 64 cores need a lot of resources. Right?

Comment: Well, each of these cores can be simpler than say your standard Intel Core i core and for a 650-700€ card I don't think using 32-64 cores / a specialized FPGA / ASIC is too unreasonable.

Comment: A fast Montgomery multiplier will do wonders already. My measly 2 core laptop with i7m - and without large number multiplier - already performs over 1200 signs / second using `openssl speed rsa2048` by the way, so your "fast version" is not that fast. And that's not even using the modern instructions by Intel to make faster ops possible as the CygWin OpenSSL version is very old. And I'm pretty sure that's single threaded as well (yes, it is, it produces higher results with `-multi 2`, and I only have 2 cores). Who sponsors my new 12 core AMD system?

Comment: I just found out that a Sparc T1 (that's a processor from 2005) did over 60K ops for RSA 1024. Go figure what an optimized CPU can do now. And yes, the latest Intel CPU's have special instructions to speed up things like this in hardware (or at least microcode). E.g. see the functions defined [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-crypto-reference-2019-montmul) for modular multiplication and squaring. The instructions used are called [`AVX-512_IFMA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#New_instructions_in_AVX-512_IFMA).

Comment: Oh, yeah, no, specialized hardware using a ring and asynchronous operation, definitely Montgomery in HW - and definitely not just one. [Here](https://www.servethehome.com/intel-quickassist-technology-and-openssl-setup-insights-and-initial-benchmarks/) is some more info. Requires OpenSSL 1.1.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, thanks. Yes, your are right. There's a lot of room for improvement in my design and I will try to make a smaller and faster montgomery multiplier. The command `openssl speed rsa2048 -multi 12` shows 14K ops in my server.

Comment: Note that this Intel solution likely uses a fully asynchronous hardware solution with a 4Kib buffer. In software, you won't get close even if you use vectoring instructions. I mean, similar technology can make RSA go fast on an 8 bit smart card with almost no power consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Specialized hardware is the answer. This machine uses asynchronous computation, very likely using parallel Montgomery multipliers and a local register of 4096 bits (4096 seems to be the largest key size for RSA, so we can conclude that this is the size of the register). Similar hardware can be found in Smart Card CPU's. These don't go as fast, because they are hampered by low power consumption, TDP, a relatively slow - often 8/16 bit - CPU and large transistor sizes. The solution requires OpenSSL 1.1 to utilize the asynchronous API that the Intel QuickAssist hardware offers.

Newer Intel chips have vectoring instructions that also help to speedup the multiplication and squaring required to perform fast modular exponentiation (the base of any RSA calculation). However, they don't offer a Montgomery multiplier of sufficient size to overtake fully specialized hardware (actually, the use of the vectoring constructions may quickly lead to overheating and scaling down of processor frequencies).

It's unlikely you can beat specialized hardware in software; modular exponentiation is not a cheap operation (it's only fast compared to finding large primes required for RSA key pair generation). Furthermore, you may make a very fast implementation that is not protected against side channel attacks, which is a major requirement for keeping your private key secure.

Note that the specialized hardware is not an RSA accelerator (that the software delivered with the hardware does offer). It performs the mathematical operations more quickly. It can also be used to speed up (EC)DH and (EC)DSA, for instance.

Comment: For RSA4096, the size of the register is probably 2048 (because of the CRT optimization, and optimizing the public key operation is not that critical)

Comment: On the smartcards the buffer simply holds the entire value before / after, you need I/O after all. But I imagine that there is buffering within the operation itself as well.

Comment: This card use Intel® Communications Chipset 8950. I think this card use CRT-RSA for RSA2048 sign operation. Because there is some crt-rsa function in QAT api. I am not sure that this chipset may has several modexp cores.

Comment: The speed that they advertise is almost always CRT, but commonly this will "only" speed up operation 2-4 times, so the numbers would be suspiciously high for one multiplier (although not impossible). Thinking again, I think poncho is right, and this may be just a 2048 bit multiplier though.